# Как сверстать ​линию чтобы она сама растягиваться между точками?

Tags: html, css

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Сайт на wordpress и необходимо сделать такой список, где контент может быть разный по размерам. Как сделать такую ​​версту чтобы линия сама растягивалась между точками?

Comment: Через border-left

Comment: @Qwertiy как задать высоту border до половины пункта списка?

Comment: Заменить на псевдоэлемент для первого и последнего элементов, например. Или использовать тень. Или накрыть другим блоком.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
.white_line_top{
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  background-color: #fff;
  width: 5px;
  height: 50%;
}
.white_line_bot{
    position: absolute;
  bottom: 0px;
  background-color: #fff;
  width: 5px;
  height: 50%;
}
```

Воспользовался советом из комментария, и перекрыл полоску. Нужно добавить 2 блока, один над верхней точкой, и один под нижней

Answer (score 3):

Держите:

```css
li {
  list-style: none;
  position: relative;
  padding: 0.5em 1em 0.5em 25px;
}

li:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  width: 15px;
  height: 15px;
  display: block;
  background-color: gray;
  left: 5px;
  border-radius: 100px;
  transform: translatey(-50%);
}

li:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  left:12px;
  bottom:0;
  top:0;
  display:block;
  width:1px;
  background-color: gray;
}

li:first-child:after {top:50%;}

li:last-child:after {bottom:50%;}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>text</li>
  <li>text<br/>text</li>
  <li>text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text
    text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text </li>
  <li>text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text </li>
</ul>
```